# Имена числительные: управление

Tags: управление, числительные

*Глазам достаточно несколько цветов* или *глазам достаточно нескольких цветов?*

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***глазам достаточно нескольких цветов.***

***Достаточно*** — предикативное наречие, используется в безличном предложении в функции сказуемого.

Управление Р.п.: ***достаточно пяти цветов, достаточно нескольких цветов.***

***Несколько*** —  неопределенно-количественное числительное, склоняется как полное прилагательное, имеет полную парадигму склонения: несколько, нескольких, нескольким и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Теймураз!

*Даже несколько цветов достаточно хорошо смотрятся в этой вазе. - Глазам достаточно нескольких цветов.*

Здесь "[достаточно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)" в разных функциях, не это слово определяет число и падеж.